# How to read values of arrays in objects

Tags: javascript

I want to assign values of dataElement and category of des[] to different variables in a loop, Can any body help me?

```js
var deMapping = {
            RBSK: {'dsUID': 'tdTwLUxcQ8R', rootNodeName: 'RBSK_GIS_Indicator', orgUnitTagName: 'MCTSCode', des: [
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Female",
                    dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Male",
                    dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_7_18_Female",
                    dataElement: "cEPledgs7rd",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                }]}
  }
```

Comment: not really clear on your objective, if it is just to assign those values to another variable, why do you need to loop?

Comment: What loop ? Where is your attempt? This isn't a code writing service. You will however get lots of help when you show the code that isn't working and provide a proper explanation of what it should do

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to grab values and assign them to a variable try this:

```
var x = deMapping.RBSK.des[0].dataElement // => "oV163sbcJ0N"
```

that line will grab the dataElement value from the first object inside of the `des` property's array of objects. You can continue to grab elements like this without looping. Unless you for some reason need to loop. That part isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you having trouble with? Just knowing how to get data from that object? The dot operator?

That is an object named deMapping. The deMapping object has 1 property called RBSK, which is an object. So far you'd go `deMapping.RBSK` to get this far. That RBSK object has 4 properties (dsUID, rootNodeName, orgUnitTagName, and des). The first 3 listed are string values, the last one (des) is an array. To access that array you'd be going `deMapping.RBSK.des`. That array has 3 values. You'd access them with `deMapping.RBSK.des[0]` (the example being the 0 index, since arrays are indexed from zero). Each of those array values are objects, each of them having 3 possible properties to access (xmlid, dataElement, and categoryOptionCombo). So again, dot operator would be used to access those. So at this point to access the dataElement of the 3rd array value (which will be 2, since it's indexed from zero...so 0, 1, and 2) it would go `deMapping.RBSK.des[2].dataElement`

An example of looping through would be something like this.

```
var j = deMapping.RBSK.des.length;
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    var theDataElement = deMapping.RBSK.des[i].dataElement;
    var theCategoryOptionCombo = deMapping.RBSK.des[i].categoryOptionCombo;
    // do something with those values.
}
```